# Why can enum arrays be cast to two different IEnumerable<T> types?

Tags: c#, arrays, enums

I seemed to have stumbled upon something unusual within C# that I don't fully understand.  Say I have the following enum defined:

```
public enum Foo : short 
{
    // The values aren't really important
    A,
    B
}
```

If I declare an array of `Foo` or retrieve one through `Enum.GetValues`, I'm able to successfully cast it to both `IEnumerable<short>` and `IEnumerable<ushort>`.  For example:

```
Foo[] values = Enum.GetValues( typeof( Foo ) );
// This cast succeeds as expected.
var asShorts = (IEnumerable<short>) values;
// This cast also succeeds, which wasn't expected.
var asUShorts = (IEnumerable<ushort>) values;
// This cast fails as expected:
var asInts = (IEnumerable<int>) values;
```

This happens for other underlying types as well.  Arrays of enums always seem to be castable to both the signed and unsigned versions of the underlying integral type.

I'm at a loss for explaining this behavior.  Is it well-defined behavior or have I just stumbled onto a peculiar quirk of the language or CLR?

Comment: As soon as you declare an enumeration with a negative value, the `ushort` cast should implode.

Comment: @ps2goat: No it won't. It'll just use the same bits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not just `IEnumerable<T>` - you can cast it to the *array* type as well, so long as you fool the compiler first:

```
public enum Foo : short 
{
    A, B
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo[] foo = new Foo[10];
        short[] shorts = (short[]) (object) foo;
        ushort[] ushorts = (ushort[]) (object) foo;        
    }
}
```

The C# language provides no expectation of this conversion being feasible, but the CLR is happy to do it. The reverse is true too - you could cast from a `short[]` to a `Foo[]`. Oh, and if you had another enum with the same underlying type, you could cast to that, too. Basically, the CLR knows that all of these types are just 16-bit integers - all bit patterns are valid values, even though they'll have different meanings - so it lets you treat one type as another. I don't *think* that's documented in the CLI specification - I couldn't find any reference to it, anyway.

This can cause some interesting problems when optimizations in LINQ (in `Cast<>` and `ToList`) are combined, just for the record.

For example:

```
int[] foo = new int[10];
var list = foo.Cast<uint>().ToList();
```

You might expect this to come up with an `InvalidCastException` (as it does if you start with a `List<int>` with any values, for example) but instead you end up with:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type.
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.SZArrayHelper.CopyTo[T](T[] array, Int32 index)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Test.Main()
```

That's because the `Cast` operation has checked and found that the `int[]` is already a `uint[]`, so it's passed it right along to `ToList()`, which then tries to use `Array.Copy`, which *does* notice the difference. Ouch!

Comment: Interesting thing is that enum array implements both `IEnumerable<EnumName>` and `IEnumerable<UnderlyingType>`.