# Fastest way to save/load enum[] (byte) to a file

Tags: c#, optimization, serialization

The array has duplicate elements and their order is important (must be kept).  I have to save/load hundreds of these files constantly and each file may hold an array up to 100,000 elements.

The code bellow is an example of what I'm currently doing to save/load the files. Since IO is slow I got a significant speed improvement by casting the enums to byte before serialization (reducing the file size by 10x). I'm not sure I should be using BinaryFormatter though.

I'm still looking for improvements as everything should be as quick as possible, is there a better alternative to what I'm currently doing? How would you do it?

```
enum DogBreed : byte { Bulldog, Poodle, Beagle, Rottweiler, Chihuahua }

DogBreed[] myDogs = { DogBreed.Beagle, DogBreed.Poodle, DogBreed.Beagle, DogBreed.Bulldog };

public void Save(string path)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    byte[] myDogsInByte = Array.ConvertAll(myDogs, new Converter<DogBreed, byte>(DogBreedToByte));
    formatter.Serialize(stream, myDogsInByte);
    stream.Close();
}

public bool Load(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        return false;
    }

    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    byte[] myDogsInByte = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as byte[];
    myDogs = Array.ConvertAll(myDogsInByte, new Converter<byte, DogBreed>(ByteToDogBreed));
    stream.Close();
    return true;
}

private byte DogBreedToByte(DogBreed db)
{
    return (byte)db;
}

private DogBreed ByteToDogBreed(byte bt)
{
    return (DogBreed)bt;
}
```

EDIT: New code based on Jeremy suggestion, the code is working, I'll try to test the performance of it and post the results here as soon as I can.

```
enum DogBreed : byte { Bulldog, Poodle, Beagle, Rottweiler, Chihuahua }

DogBreed[] myDogs = { DogBreed.Beagle, DogBreed.Poodle, DogBreed.Beagle, DogBreed.Bulldog };

public void Save(string path)
{       
    byte[] myDogsInByte = new byte[myDogs.Length];
    Array.Copy(myDogs,myDogsInByte,myDogs.Length);
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, myDogsInByte);
}

public bool Load(string path)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        return false;
    }

    byte[] myDogsInByte = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    myDogs = (DogBreed[])(object)myDogsInByte;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be using `BinaryFormatter`. Just read the bytes as you would read any binary file, with a raw `Stream`, then cast each byte read to the enum value. Play with the stream's buffer size to get the best performance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why that would be the best approach? I've read someplace else about using File.WriteAllBytes and File.ReadAllBytes. I know next to nothing about serialization performance.

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/30740756/4139809 suggests you might be able to `myDogs = (DogBreed[])(object)myDogsInByte;` ?

Comment: "Object must be an array of primitives". Hmmmm, so file streams don't like being tricked with `enum[]`. So you could use; `var bytes = new byte[myDogs.Length]; Array.Copy(myDogs, bytes, myDogs.Length);` to copy from enum's to bytes.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I updated the question with your suggestions. Will try to measure performance and post it here later. Thank you for everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the C# compiler will complain if you attempt to directly assign a `byte[]` to an enum   array. The runtime doesn't care.

```cs
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
myDogs = (DogBreed[])(object)bytes;
```

The VS debugger will show that myDogs is really a byte array, but accessing an element from the array works just fine.

Update;

> ArgumentException: Object must be an array of primitives.

So `File.WriteAllBytes()` doesn't like being tricked with an `enum[]`. You should be able to to use `Array.Copy` to quickly duplicate the enum values into a `byte[]`.

```cs
   var buffer = new byte[myDogs.Length];
   Array.Copy(myDogs, buffer, myDogs.Length);
   File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);
```

Of course that's not a free operation, but it should be fairly fast even for large arrays.

Comment: Right, array element. That's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, not having to convert the array is really great. Any idea on why ReadAllBytes is best suited for this, other than the Stream aproach suggested by Etienne?

Comment: It's just the simplest api to read the whole file to a byte array. `stream.Read()` doesn't have to return the number of bytes you asked for.

Comment: Of course if you don't actually need the whole file in memory at once, you could refactor your api so you can stream the elements in and out.

Comment: So I just tested the `myDogs = (DogBreed[])(object)bytes;` approach, it actually slows things down considerably for it increases the file size by 10x. It's just like saving the enum[] directly.

Comment: Your question defined `enum DogBreed : byte`, is this not true in your performance test? There should be no runtime difference between `DogBreed[]` and `byte[]`. No per-element runtime cost to `byte[] value = (byte[])(object)enumArray`.

Comment: Thank you for your time Jeremy. Yes, I'm using the code found in the question. In Save using `byte[] myDogsInByte = Array.ConvertAll(myDogs, new Converter<DogBreed, byte>(DogBreedToByte))` produces a 32 bytes file. Replacing it for `byte[] myDogsInByte = (byte[])(object)myDogs` produces a 209 bytes file. Should the cast you suggested only be used for reading the file?

Comment: If the file length is not exactly the array length, you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Left BinaryFormatter as it was and didn't realize I couldn't use it with the cast you suggested. Just to be clear, I really can't do `byte[] myDogsInByte = (byte[])(object)myDogs` to write the file? I tried it and I'm getting `ArgumentException: Object must be an array of primitives.`. Should I convert the array for writing, like I'm currently doing?

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes(myDogsInByte)` should just write the byte array. But you are using a serialiser, which uses reflection to discover type information, embeds that information in the file. And the other clue thats already in my answer, the runtime type information of the array doesn't change when you cast it this way. It does however allow you to just call read / write functions.

Comment: Thank you for you patience so far. I'm not a native speaker and maybe I wasn't able to express myself in the best way. I've edited the question with the code I'm curretly talking about. Maybe you can tell where did I miss.